# How to upload file with a new name to GCP bucket in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I have a local file called "space.jpg" in my server.

and now I want to upload this file with a new name to GCP bucket.

I can upload this file successfully with the below code:

```
const myBucket= gc.bucket('my-bucket')
app.post('/create_file', async (req, res, next) => {
   myBucket.upload("space.jpg")
}
```

> my file structure in server
>
> - server.js
> - space.jpg

Now I want to upload this file with a random id when users request.

e.g.

```
app.post('/create_file', async (req, res, next) => {
   // spaceId = random string
   // upload space.jpg to myBucket with the name spaceId 
}
```

How to upload with a new name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to pass a second argument to [upload()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload), which is an [UploadOptions](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#UploadOptions) object.  It has a property called destination where you can name the path where the file should be uploaded.

```
const options = {
  destination: bucket.file('/path/to/newFile.jpg'),
};

myBucket.upload("space.jpg", options);
```

You will, of course, have to provide your own file name.